# Webservice don't receive any object from Android

Tags: android, web-services, soap, marshalling

I am sending from Android to my Webservice (.NET) my object, but Webservice tells me that he don't receive anything. I don't know where is the problem - it's about Android or Webservice?

Methods etc. should be fine, because I am able to receive items from Webservice. Also my method looks fine and don't throws any errors.

**myMethod**

```
final String METHOD_NAME = "SetMyProduct";
final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService1/SetMyProduct";

myAdd objToSend = new myAdd();
objToSend.setProperty(0, "aaa");
objToSend.setProperty(1, "bbb");
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("myAdd");
pi.setValue(objToSend);
pi.setType(myAdd.class);
request.addProperty(pi);


SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                       //soapEnvelope.bodyOut = request; 

soapEnvelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, myAdd.class.getSimpleName(), myAdd.class);

Marshal floatMarshal = new MarshalFloat();
floatMarshal.register(soapEnvelope);

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    try {
                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);//call the eb service Method
                        //Log.i("soapEnvelope", String.valueOf(soapEnvelope));
                        //Log.i("request", String.valueOf(request));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("error", String.valueOf(e));
                        }
```

**myAdd class**

```
public class myAdd implements KvmSerializable {
    String Nazwa; 
    String Nazwa2;

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
    switch (arg0){
        case 0:
            return Nazwa;
        case 1:
            return Nazwa2;
        default:
            return null;
            }
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return 2;//because you have 2 parameters
    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int arg0, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo arg2) {
    switch(arg0)
    {

        case 0:
            arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            arg2.name = "Nazwa";
            break;
        case 1:
            arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            arg2.name = "Nazwa2";
            break;
        default:break;
    }

    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int arg0, Object arg1) {
    switch(arg0)
    {
        case 0:
            Nazwa =  (String)arg1;
            break;
        case 1:
            Nazwa2 =  (String)arg1;           
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```